# How to explain this result about $\pi$ and $\arctan$ function?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, continued-fractions

Let $x$ denotes an integer such that $x > 1$.
We define the function $f$ such that:
$$f(x)=\frac{1}{\pi}\arctan(x)$$
We have:
$$f(x)=\cfrac{1}{a+\cfrac{1}{b+\cfrac{1}{c+\cfrac{1}{d+...}}}}$$ ($a, b, c, d$ are integers $\geq 1$)
I want to prove that: $$\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{x}{b} \approx 1.27$$
For example with $x=1000$ we have:
$$f(1000)=\cfrac{1}{2+\cfrac{1}{784+\cfrac{1}{1+\cfrac{1}{8+...}}}}$$
And $$\frac{1000}{784} \approx 1.27$$

Thanks.

Comment: Yes but when $x$ tends to $\infty$, $b$ tends to $\infty$ too, I suspect that the limit is of the form $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$

Comment: [+1] Interesting question !

Comment: What you mean with $\approx 1.27$? How exact? Might the limit be $4/\pi$?

Comment: As it turns out, the limit is $4/\pi.$

Comment: $a=2$ when $x\geq \sqrt3.$ When $x>\sqrt3,$ $b$ is the largest integer such that $$\frac b{2b+1}<\frac1{\pi}\arctan(x).$$

Answer (score 3):

Hint: $$\frac\pi2-\arctan(x)=\arctan\left(\frac1x\right)\sim \frac 1{ x}.$$ as $x\to\infty.$

---

Addition: You'll get $b$ is the nearest integer to $\frac{\pi x}4-1.$  So the limit of $\frac xb$ is $\frac{4}{\pi}\approx 1.27324.$